# QtCreator editor don't highlight Qt includes with CMake project

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I've got big CMake project depending on local qt.

I want to work with it with Qt Creator. I can build it fully fine there and I even can debug it and see variables in runtime.

The only problem is that Editor don't see qt headers and headers of depending projects in editing time and shows yellow underline below includes so I've got no auto-complete there etc...

Is it possible to help Qt Creator to parse the code by alike providing path to those includes specially for editor features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify relative paths to directories containing the header and source files in Qt Creator options:
[image: Qt Creator File Naming Options]

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, I had exactly the same issue after some QtCreator update.

The problem there is that QtCreator automatically gets your header files in your project, but it doesn't recognize them as Qt dependent somehow. Here is what I did:

```
set (HDRS Foo.hpp Bar.hpp)

# and then at the bottom of your project:

# adding a dummy target that won't be building by default 
# (and neither should be built manually)
add_executable (ShowHeadersInQtCreatorFfs
                EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL
                ${HDRS})
# just put the same libs as with your main executable
target_link_libraries(ShowHeadersInQtCreatorFfs Qt5::Core Qt5::Network)
```

So what I had to do is pretty nasty at the first glance, but it should help. Also it helped me to get all of my headers into the project (instead of having only those which have the same basenames as .cpp files)

Comment: I don't think this was the original question. This answer is "how to get QtCreator to show my headers in the Projects view", but the question was why does QtCreator yellow underline some includes even though the build system finds them ok?" (i.e. these may not even be headers that are part of your project (3rd party libraries, etc.))

Comment: "Is it possible to help Qt Creator to parse the code by alike providing path to those includes specially for editor features?" -- I answered to this part, and my answer is what I keep using to fix exact problem in question (no need to configure each QtCreator version I use). As of your interpretation, there is an interesting thing coming up in future version of QtCreator https://blog.qt.io/blog/2016/11/15/cmake-support-in-qt-creator-and-elsewhere/ -- there author kinda elaborates why was it always hard for an IDE to get all the data from CMake.